# avoiding name conflicts with rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, models

I am using gnuplot gem to create some plots from within the app.  I also have a model called `Vector`.  Without getting into too many details, gnuplot gem creates a conflict with the `Vector` model.  When I comment out the gem from the config file the problem goes away.  If I am using the gem the app simply does not see any methods in the `Vector` model. gnuplot is not needed by the `Vector` model.  Is there any remedy for this?

This is a rails 2 app.

Config File gems:

```
  config.gem "json"

  config.gem "prawn"
  config.gem "prawn-core", :lib => "prawn/core"
  config.gem "prawn-layout", :lib => "prawn/layout"
```

Comment: Can you show us your Gemfile? Gnuplot gem doesn't define Vector (at least that I can see, but the GSL gem does.

Comment: I've run into this so many times. Gem authors should namespace their classes more often, or at least use overly specific names. I usually either fork the offending library and just rename the class there, or rename my own app class to get around it.